# jQuery sub-selector can't find DOM objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following markup:

```
<span class="checkbox group_delivery checkbox_checked">1</span>
<span class="checkbox group_delivery">2</span>
<span class="checkbox group_delivery">3</span>
```

I try to check if there is at least one `checkbox` within `group_delivery` that is `checked`.

So I look for a tag which has `group_delivery` and `checkbox_checked` classes.

I've tried the followings:

```
$('.checkbox_checked', $('.group_delivery')) - 0 results
$('.group_delivery').find('.checkbox_checked') - 0 results
```

But if I loop through the `$('.group_delivery')` object with `.each` I can find the desired span:

```
    $('.group_delivery').each(function(i,o) {
        if ($(o).hasClass('checkbox_checked')) {
            console.log('Found in each loop');
        }
    });
```

You can check that in this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fenistil/bc35cgq9/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.find` (and the `$(selector, parent)` form) looks for **descendants**, i.e. it would look for `.checkbox_checked` elements **inside** `.group_delivery` elements.

However, you want to find elements that have both classes:

```
$('.group_delivery.checkbox_checked')
```

Alternatively you could use [`.filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
$('.group_delivery').filter('.checkbox_checked')
```

---

> But if I loop through the `$('.group_delivery')` object with `.each` I can find the desired span:

Because `.hasClass` checks whether *the element itself* has this class.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It's funny that I've tried `$('.group_delivery .checkbox_checked')` first, but with a space between the two classes, so the problem was a single space :)

Comment: space will again look for descendants..space and no space is completely different meaning.